# How to ORDER BY with UNION in SQL with column ALIASES?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, alias

Here is my very simple MYSQL request :

```
(SELECT start, name, id, info FROM `table1`)
UNION
(SELECT end, name, id, info FROM `table1`)
```

I want to sort the result by 1st column and I guessed I need to use aliases:

```
(SELECT start as mydate, name, id, info FROM `table1`)
UNION
(SELECT end as mydate, name, id, info FROM `table1`)
ORDER BY mydate
```

I was surprised that MYSQL threw this error :

```
 "Unknown column 'mydate' in 'where clause'"
```

I ended with this working bad practice :

```
(SELECT start, name, id, info FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT end, name, id, info FROM table1)
ORDER BY 1
```

source: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

But I would like to understand my error !

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on  [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/er3wTJYdmFKYLsiABaw6bU/1). Is what you have posted the exact SQL you are running? It seems strange that your error message references a where clause when you have not shown one.

Comment: Is your query part of another, larger query?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error either. Neither in MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, nor in MySQL 8. The parentheses are not needed. Nonetheless, with parentheses or without, the query should run just fine. What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I agree with other comments it is working with different versions and "ORDER BY mydate"  is not giving any error, also try removing the parentheses. please your version details

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested query.

```sql
SELECT q.* 
  FROM (
              SELECT start as mydate, name, id, info FROM `table1`
              UNION ALL
              SELECT end as mydate, name, id, info FROM `table1`
       ) AS q
 ORDER BY q.mydate
```

The inner query builds up your result set and the outer one orders it.  The MySQL query planner is reasonably smart about optimizing this sort of thing.

By the way `UNION` removes duplicates and `UNION ALL` does not.

Comment: There is no need to nest it. OP already claims `ORDER BY 1` is working.

Comment: Well, OK. I stand by my answer because it points to a general solution to the problem of manipulating the result sets of UNION operations.